# Extending Django PositiveIntegerField to automatically pad string representation?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wondering if there's a best way to extend one of my model's fields to automatically pad the string representation of a PositiveIntegerField

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    coupon_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, help_text='Coupon code',)
```

admin.py:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    list_display=['username','email','coupon_code',]
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + ( ('Coupon Code', {'fields': ['coupon_code',]} ), )
```

Currently the field displays as an integer would. For example, 42 is printed as '42'. However I would like if the field would pad with zeros whenever printed across the site, especially for built-in pages like **admin**, so 42 displayed would always be displayed as '0000000042', while keeping the underlying Integer representation in the database.

Can this be done?

Comment: Something like this? `"%010d" % user_instance.coupon_code` ?

Comment: Yeah, that approach works when rendering on a custom template. However I'm trying to get this to display on pages built by other packages, like django.contrib.auth.admin. Admin loads all fields from `list_display=['username','email','coupon_code',]`. I can't control it after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zfill is your best bet, you could use a representation property or something on the class. 
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill#str.zfill

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    coupon_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, help_text='Coupon code',)

    @property
    def coupon_code_display(self):
        return self.coupon_code.zfill(10)
```

Comment: Cool idea. How would I get this to automatically display in admin? for example: `list_display=['username','email','coupon_code',]`
I tried adding the code but I don't see any change yet

Comment: Replace 'coupon_code' with 'coupon_code_display' in your list_display, and if you want it in the detail view, add it to `readonly_fields = ['coupon_code_display']` in your  CustomUserAdmin class.